# Possible to stream live video without using RTSP?

Tags: javascript, streaming, rtsp, live-streaming

Is it possible to live stream video (& audio) without using the RTSP protocol? Today I tried out Adobe's Flash Media Server and the free alternative Red5. Both seemed like a bit of an overkill (plus had issues with Red5 not supporting AAC audio).
Basically I'm looking for a way to upload live video to my server so it can be viewed using jwplayer, and then stored so it can be viewed later. Does MP4 support live streaming? So that I can record it client-side then upload it for viewing?

I've been experimenting with uploading jpg images and using a HTML5 canvas to display them so it appears like a video.
Here's my code: (using only a few images)
http://jsfiddle.net/QM5EV/

There's several things wrong with it. For one, it's not efficient because it requires mass amounts of jpg's to be uploaded. And most importantly there's no audio.

What would be best to do? Is RTSP the only sensible choice? Thanks. :)

Comment: Anyone? :) Looking at Red5 again now.

Answer (score 1):

Live via HTTP servers is, for the most part, not an option.  But there is "Apple Live Streaming" aka MPEG-TS, although that limits your clients to iOS devices.  It uses a plain ol'web server.  (This seems to be changing, increasingly desktop browsers are supporting MPEG-TS, but will probably take some time before it is common place.)

Answer (score 0):

For online streaming, rtsp is the best solution. Other protocols such as RTMP ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol) but transmit to any multimedia content using RTSP.

Another thing is that you can make a specific streaming server accepts HTTP redirect requests. Thus, instead of URL's as rtsp://mydomain.com:554/myfile.mp4 can have URL's like http://mydomain.com/myfile.mp4

Regards!